# How to cancel server-side OnTextChanged event of textbox when client-side onblur event gets fired and returns false?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net, dom-events

I've a web page with a `textbox` as below -

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtNumber" runat="server" size="5" MaxLength="9" 
    AutoPostBack="True" OnTextChanged="txtNumber_TextChanged" 
    CssClass="txtBoxPage" Style="margin-left: 3px;" 
    Visible="false" onblur="return [some JS function] false;">
</asp:TextBox>
```

I want a functionality such that if User enters `Nothing` i.e. ('') in `textbox` and move the cursor outside the `textbox` then `Postback` should not trigger. Currently it's getting triggered even after `onblur` event returns `false`.

Comment: Could you show us blur function?

Comment: If it has text originally and user deletes them and then onblur, do you want it to post back or not?

Comment: No Postback is required if user deletes the text/number from textbox and move the cursor.

Comment: Let me know if the code I posted works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If textbox value is empty, you can supress `TextChanged` event as below -

- Remove onblur function and use onchange instead.
- Add following line in Page_Load -

  ```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      txtNumber.Attributes.Add("onchange", "if(checkEmptyValue(this)) {return false; }");
  }
  ```
- Include following JavaScript in markup -

  ```
  String.prototype.trim = function() {     return this.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, ""); }; 

  function checkEmptyValue(o) {
      if (o.value == '' || o.value.trim() == '')
          return true;
      else
          return false;
  }
  ```

Try above code and let me know if it works.

Answer (score 2):

```
document.getElementById('txtnumber').onchange=function(){
    if(this.value!=""){
        _doPostBack('txtNumber',this.value);
    }
}
```

You can then retrieve the value by using the Request["__EVENTARGUMENT"] entry. Also, make sure to turn AutoPostback off.

EDIT: Within your txtNumber_TextChanged handler, for example:

```
private void txtNumber_TextChanged handler
{
    Response.Write(Request["__EVENTARGUMENT"]);
    //Writes the value of the TextBox. Basically, EVENTARGUMENT is the second argument passed when calling _doPostBack
}
```

Note that this is entirely optional, since you can still access the value of txtNumber using the txtNumber object (as is traditional).

EDIT: Note that when using document.getElementById to retrieve a reference to the element, you need to pass the client ID as the argument. If, for example the txtNumber object is within a FormView named FormView1, the resulting client ID will be FormView1_txtNumber. One of the following modifications to your code should fix the issue:

1) If your javascript is in a script tag on the aspx page, simply modify `document.getElementById('txtNumber')` to `document.getElementById('<%= txtNumber.ClientID %>')`

2) If you are using an external js file, change `document.getElementById('txtNumber')` to `document.getElementById(txtNumberClientID)` and insert the following script tag in your aspx page before you call your js file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.txtNumberClientID='<%= txtNumber.ClientID %>';
</script>
```

Let me know if this works

Comment: Can you provide Request["__EVENTARGUMENT"] logic?

Comment: I have edited my answer to include a sample of Request["_EVENTARGUMENT"] being used. Nevertheless, it is not necessary that you use this to retrieve the value, as you can use the standard txtNumber.Text property.

Comment: It's throwing Exception as - Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'document.getElementById(...)' is null or not an object.

Comment: Sumit, you need to specify the client side ID of the textbox. If the textbox is inside another control, its id will be prefixed with the id of that control. I will edit my answer to explain further.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code in jquery

```
 <script>
    $('[id$=TextBox1]').live('blur', function (e) {
        if ($('[id$=TextBox1]').val() == '') {
            alert('empty');
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        } else {
            alert('fillled');
        }
    });
</script>
```

Try this code hopefully it will work for you...